# React Final Form - Change selected value based on input from another field when it blurs

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, next.js, react-final-form

I'm using react final form to create a form.

I have an input and a select. In the input you can type a colour, in the select you can select a colour.

I'm looking to automatically trigger the onChange in the select field if a user types a matching colour into the input when the input BLURS.

How could I do that. I'm not sure how to trigger another fields onChange event when one Field blurs.

Here is a code sandbox

Link to sandbox - https://codesandbox.io/s/stupefied-hoover-5hfws?file=/src/index.js

This is the code

```
/* eslint-disable jsx-a11y/accessible-emoji */
import React from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import Styles from "./Styles";
import { Form, Field } from "react-final-form";

const sleep = (ms) => new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, ms));

const onSubmit = async (values) => {
  await sleep(300);
  window.alert(JSON.stringify(values, 0, 2));
};

const handleBlur = () => {
  console.log("Bluring");
};

const App = () => (
  <Styles>
    <h1>React Final Form - Simple Example</h1>
    <a
      href="https://final-form.org/react"
      target="_blank"
      rel="noopener noreferrer"
    >
      Read Docs
    </a>
    <Form
      onSubmit={onSubmit}
      render={({ handleSubmit, form, submitting, pristine, values }) => (
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
          <div>
            <label>Color</label>
            <Field name="color">
              {({ input, meta, props }) => (
                <div>
                  <input
                    name="f"
                    type="text"
                    onChange={input.onChange}
                    onBlur={handleBlur}
                    value={input.value}
                  />
                </div>
              )}
            </Field>
          </div>

          <div>
            <label>Favorite Color</label>
            <Field name="favoriteColor">
              {({ input, meta, props }) => (
                <div>
                  <select onChange={input.onChange}>
                    <option />
                    <option value="blue">Blue</option>
                    <option value="green">Green</option>
                    <option value="yellow">Yellow</option>
                  </select>
                </div>
              )}
            </Field>
          </div>

          <pre>{JSON.stringify(values, 0, 2)}</pre>
        </form>
      )}
    />
  </Styles>
);

render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```